Reference on multifractal complex measures?
This is a cross-post of this physicsSE post; I am also posting it here since this question lies at the boundary of both physics and math.
I am learning about multifractal formalism recently. It seems nearly all the work is done for real-valued measures.

Question: I am wondering whether there is study (or even definition!) for multifractal formalism of complex measures.

By complex measures I am refering to complex-valued measures (as defined in this wikipedia page) intead of complicated measures (which seems to be what a google serach of 'multifractal complex measures' will lead to).

A complex measure differs from a positive measure by a density $f(x)=e^{i\alpha (x)}$, which seems not very relevant in this context.

@ChristianRemling I see. So you mean it might be defined as the multifractal property of its associated total variation measure?
